# Are all values of $x$ solutions for $e^{2\ln(\sin(x))} = 1 - e^{2\ln(\cos(x))}$ in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: logarithms, wolfram-alpha

> Does all values of $x$ in $\mathbb R$ satisfy equation: $$e^{2\ln(\sin(x))} = 1 - e^{2\ln(\cos(x))}$$

I am asking this, because by checking WolframAlpha solution there is an answer: *(all values for $x$ are solutions over reals)*, but we know that $\ln(0)$ is undefined, same for negative numbers.

[Wolfram Alpha solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20e%20**%20(2ln%20sin%20x)%20%3D%201%20-%20e%20**%20(2ln%20cos%20x)%20for%20x)

Therefore I assume in $\mathbb R$, zero and negative numbers doesn't satisfy this equation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\ln*\sin(x)$? Does it refer to $\ln(\sin(x))$ or what is the meaning of this notation?

Comment: sorry, my bad. Yes. Will fix equation

Comment: Wolfram Alpha will always give explicitly Wrong Answer for some input. Any real mathematician will always be able to easily find a limit that exists but WA says it doesn't, or vice versa. Whenever someone reports a wrong answer, the programmers just hack a 'fix' based on random guesswork rather than mathematics. Bottom line: Don't trust WA to be correct even on very simple questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1=e^{2\ln\sin(x)} +e^{2\ln \cos(x)}= e^{\ln\sin^2(x)}+e^{\ln \cos^2(x)} = $$

$$ = \sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1 $$

So this is true for all $x$ such that $\sin x>0$ and $\cos x>0$ (because then is $\ln $ defined).

So $$\boxed{x\in \color{red}{\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} (0+2\pi k,{\pi\over 2}+2\pi k)}}$$

Comment: Great. I was thinking the same. Does that mean solution on Wolfram is wrong?

Comment: (+1) For myself I totally forgot to think about the existence of the natural logarithm as it is only assured for $\sin(x),\cos(x)>0$.

Comment: @PeterParada I'm not sure what is Wolfram doing. It draw you a whole line for $f(x) =e^{\ln x}$ which is absurd to me.

Comment: Thank you. I will write them for further clarification.

Comment: @PeterParada: I think Wolfram implicitly assumes that $x$ is in the domain; you might need to check documentation to see if this is standard.

Answer (score 0):

Note that :
$$e^{2\ln \sin x} + e^{2 \ln \cos x} = 1 \Rightarrow e^{\ln (\sin x)^2} + e^{\ln (\cos x)^2} = 1 \Leftrightarrow \sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1 \rightarrow \text{true} \; \forall x \in \mathbb R$$
Restrictions apply so as the initial expression holds, so that narrows down the solution set. Note the usage of $\Rightarrow$ instead of an $\Leftrightarrow$ at the start.